# How do I set the index on ng-repeated item for a ng-click?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an gallery image with thumbnails. When I click on a thumbnail, I want the main image to show the thumbnail index with it's full image. How do I add ng-click to get the current index?

```
  <div ng-controller="GalleryController as gallery">
                <img ng-src="{{product.images[gallery.current]}}" />
                <div>
                    <img ng-src="{{image.thumb}}" ng-repeat="image in product.images" ng-click="gallery.setCurrent(image[i])" />
                </div>
            </div>

       app.controller('GalleryController', function () {
            this.current = 0;

            this.setCurrent = function (val) {
                this.current = val;
            }

        });

     var gems = [
         {
           images: [
                 {
                     full: 'img/diamond.jpg',
                     thumb: 'img/diamond.jpg'
                 },
                    {
                        full: 'img/diamond2.jpg',
                        thumb: 'img/diamond2.jpg'
                    }

             ]},

        ];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass the `image` object itself or use `$index` (ng-repeat puts this property on its scope) which will have the index of the currently iterated item.

Passing current image item:-

```
<img ... ng-repeat="image in product.images" ng-click="gallery.setCurrent(image)" />
```

or passing index of that item:-

```
<img ... ng-repeat="image in product.images" ng-click="gallery.setCurrent($index)" />
```